# Ctrl+Alt+Fn Virtual console not working in Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS with nVidia 535 driver

Tags: nvidia, kernel, graphics, 22.04

I'm having this problem with Ubuntu 22.04. Virtual Terminals do not work anymore, do not show the login prompt and they only show the BIOS messages at the start, the same displayed when I turn on the PC.

Version information:

```
Versión 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) de 64 bits
Núcleo Linux 6.2.0-31-generic x86_64
MATE 1.26.0
```

```
$ inxi
CPU: 12-core AMD Ryzen 9 7900 (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 3019/3000/5481 MHz
Kernel: 6.2.0-31-generic x86_64 Up: 44m Mem: 16585.4/63431.2 MiB (26.1%)
Storage: 6.37 TiB (31.6% used) Procs: 685 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

```
$inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: nvidia v: 535.104.05
  Device-2: AMD driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Razer USA Gaming Webcam [Kiyo] type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Device-4: DisplayLink Kensington SD3600 Dual Video Dock type: USB
    driver: cdc_ncm,snd-usb-audio
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    gpu: nvidia,amdgpu resolution: 2560x1440
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.104.05
```

I don't know if this is related, but every time I upgrade the system when video/kernel updates are available, video goes off and I must reset, then when logging on again doing a dpkg --configure -a

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Problem was with some nVidia kernel files.
I installed Nouveau drivers, rebooted, uninstalled/purged all remaining nVidia files, including:

- linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-31-generic
- linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2-31-generic
- mate-optimus

rebooted, checked that I can switch to virtual terminals CRTL+ALT+F1/F7, and once I make sure they work, reinstalled the nVidia 535 privative drivers, and tested virtual terminals again.
All is working now.